# ssh on ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I want to ssh connect to an ubuntu server, from my windows 10.

I'm newbie in installing ssh.

I followed the tutorial, but its not working.
what am I missing here ?

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

btw: no firewall on the ubuntu.

I installed (on ubuntu) ssh with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

I checked ip adress, with:  `wget -qO- ifconfig.co`

I checked the status:

```
sudo service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-03-08 18:07:03 IST; 23min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 119478 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38400)
     Memory: 1.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─119478 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Succeeded.
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 sshd[119478]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 sshd[119478]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 08 18:07:03 dianne-H270-HD3 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

but I can't ssh out of ubuntu or into ubuntu.
I get from windows
`ssh: connect to host xxx port 22: Connection timed out`

and the same from the ubuntu

```
ssh: connect to host yyy port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: What is in between your Windows PC and the Ubuntu server? are the on the same LAN, or separated by a router, or connected by a public (internet) connection?

Comment: The IP address from `wget -qO- ifconfig.co` is likely your *router's* IP address. Use `ip a` to get your Ubuntu system's IP address within your LAN. Try that LAN IP address from other systems within your LAN.

Comment: @steeldriver completely separate, don't share nothing.

Comment: @user535733 I tried that. its not working as well.

Comment: You might want to check on Superuser instead. SSH usually just works on Ubuntu. With windows, you might have to mess with the firewall to allow outgoing/incoming requests.

Comment: Also, if no firewall, why `sudo ufw allow ssh`?

Comment: OK so I'm not sure what "don't share nothing" means in this context, but if the Ubuntu server is behind a router (so that your `wget` command returns a public IP address) then most likely you need to configure that router to forward SSH traffic from the router's port to the server's port.